# Haskell : find missing instance with GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

I wrote a Haskell program with many data type such as :

```
data MyType = FirstType Int Int
            | SecondType [Double]
            | ThirdType Double Double Double
            ...
```

and with some instance for these data types such as :

```
instance Show MyType where
  show (FirstType a b ) = "Some Messages "++show a++show b++" End"
  show (SecondType list ) = "Another Message "++show (head list)
```

Is there a GHC option to find **incomplete instance declaration** (the missing `show (ThirdType a b c ) =` above) and avoid a program failure?

More extensively, what are the most common GHC options to find **mistakes** or **omissions** in a Haskell program? And what can they find?

Comment: Have you tried `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`?

Comment: I recommend using `-Wall` to enable all warnings. Some/most of them should be on by default IMHO.

Comment: If you use `-Wall` and `-Werror` then you'll catch a lot more problems with your code.